# 'pwd' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Tags: cmd, environment-variables

I am getting **'pwd' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file** when I am trying to check my present working directory from cmd.

I have already set the environment variable path. Still I am getting the issue.
ping, cmd is working fine.

Please help. thanks in advance

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

Comment: Or else [tag:java] has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comman)

Answer (score 27):

`pwd` is a linux command, won't work in windows.

In windows just run `cd` without passing any arguments

Comment: This works on my windows development machine. It works in cmd.exe. I'd be interested to know why it works.  I did install Git Bash.

Comment: also works in anaconda prompt - thanks

Answer (score 3):

'pwd' works on "windows Powershell" instead of "command prompt/cmd" from windows 10

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JupyterLab, 
!pwd is unacceptable as it is for the the linux,
for window use pwd ,instead.